# Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key with com.crealytics:spark-excel

Tags: azure, maven, databricks, azure-databricks, maven-exec-plugin

I have setup my Databricks notebook to use Service Principal to access ADLS using below confguration.

```
service_credential = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>",key="<service-credential-key>")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

I am able to read csv file from ADLS however getting `Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key` with excel file. Below is the code to read excel file.

```
#libaray used com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.2.2_0.18.0

df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!A1:BA100000")\
    .option("delimiter", ",") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("multiline", "true") \
    .load(file_path_full)
```

#### Stack Trace

```
 Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:51)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:577)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:1832)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:224)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:537)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.readFromHadoop$1(WorkbookReader.scala:60)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.$anonfun$apply$4(WorkbookReader.scala:79)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.$anonfun$openWorkbook$3(WorkbookReader.scala:102)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:251)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.openWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:102)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:33)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook$(WorkbookReader.scala:32)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:87)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:48)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt(ExcelRelation.scala:48)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:121)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns(ExcelRelation.scala:120)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.$anonfun$inferSchema$1(ExcelRelation.scala:189)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:188)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:52)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:52)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:29)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:24)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.diagnostics.ConfigurationBasicValidator.validate(ConfigurationBasicValidator.java:49)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.diagnostics.Base64StringConfigurationBasicValidator.validate(Base64StringConfigurationBasicValidator.java:40)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.validateStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:70)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:49)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, found the solution.
Need to add following configuration as well.

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution Deepak. Looks to work for the spark-xml context as well!